# bash: How to efficiently find root nodes given set of parent-child

Tags: shell-script, osx, numeric-data

I have a huge (few GBs) file of parent-ID, child-ID pairs. I also have an (incomplete) set of known root nodes.

For each of the known child nodes I need to find a root node, i.e. the one either not having a known further parent-child pair, or belonging to a set of known root nodes. After I find such a root node, I need to write it as a third field to the above set of pairs.

What is most efficient tool(s) and approach for that in command-line environment?

Assume an average node to be ~5-10 levels deep from root; hundreds of leaf nodes peaking at over hundred levels deep.

I need a portability between MacOS (High Sierra) and some Gnu/Linux; I have GNU set of tools on MacOS; free to install further command-line tools both on Mac and Linux. Assume 4GB RAM on both platforms; decent SSD; outdated CPU.

Comment: Are the IDs integers? How big are they?

Comment: Numbers, int or bigint depending on point of view :-) Typically 20 digits each.

Comment: OK, and how are the pairs formatted? `parentID-childID\n` or `parentID<space>childID\n` or something?

Comment: Please provide example input and output data. Use code formatting to represent the text properly

Comment: @Useless With a single pass of awk / sort I can make it formatted with any delimiter, these are marginally cheap operations compared to the rest.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a database, not a script.

Comment: @glennjackman The legacy is too big to consider using DB for s single problem at hand.

Comment: Well, if you want  to code this yourself, you'll have to partition your data so it fits in memory. This seems like the kind of problem that database engines are for.

Comment: You may possibly want to look into using `tsort`.  It would be nice to see a small example of your data.

Comment: My idea here is to use `join(1)` to get from `parent child` to `grandparent parent child` (add a first column with the grandparent), then repeat to get the great-grandparent and so on, until there's no more nodes to find... Might take some effort, but it's definitely an interesting problem to solve!

Comment: @fibranden What is complexity of your approach? Sounds like it is `(level of deepest node)` passes, and each `join` should be `O(N)`, and each pass likely means re-reading of the entire list of pairs--and writing it to a temporary file.

Comment: @glennjackman How would you approach finding a proper criteria for partinioning?

Comment: I would be as lazy as possible and let the database engine figure it out.

Comment: `join` uses O(1) space which seems to be the biggest restriction you have (data set much larger than memory.) It requires a `sort(1)` each step, and `sort(1)` is good with using temporary files to sort files larger than memory. I believe you might need like 5x diskspace to be able to run this approach. Regarding time complexity, it seems sorting (with O(n log n)) is the most expensive operation. You have to repeat that cycle O(level of deepest node), but on each step fewer nodes are left, so the long tail is much cheaper...

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the suggestion, definitely worth a try. Still wondering how an example of data can make the difference in this context.

Comment: @wassrubleff As with most questions here, having a sample of the input data and the expected outcome from transforming that data would help tremendously in answering the question as it would then be possible to test and verify solutions, and also to check that one has actually understood the issue. I, for example, find it much easier to look at the data than to try to make sense of an _explanation_ of the data and the needed transformation.

Comment: I'll follow that too. A sample of the input data and your expected output _for that sample_, please.

Comment: Just implemented the approach I proposed and added an answer for it. Hopefully you'll find it useful! Cheers.

Comment: @Kusalananda In theory, `tsort` description and `man` looks promising, but it would be very helpful if you could detail how exactly it could be applied to the problem at hand.

Comment: @wassrubleff I'd be happy to consider this issue if there were some sample data to test my solution against.

Comment: @Kusalananda Will prepare and post it in a day or two, it takes some time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your file has 2 columns, separated by some character

Looking at the question a little more carefully, a root node will never appear as a child. Keep track of the parents in an array, and increment the count when it's a child. The array keys with zero count will be root nodes.

```
awk -F, '
   !($1 in p) {p[$1]=0}   # register a parent in the array
   {p[$2]++}              # increment the count when it's seen as a child
   END {for (n in p) if (p[n] == 0) print n}
' bigfile
```

---

As @filbranden points out, this only locates the root nodes.

We have a similar situtation at work: in an Oracle db, there's a table that contains parent-child entries. We created a view that would map the child id to the *path* of ids leading to the parent:

```
id parent_id
 1 null
 2 1
 3 2
 4 1
 5 null
 6 5
```

and the view looks like

```
id id_path
 1 1
 2 1\2
 3 1\2\3
 4 1\4
 5 5
 6 5\6
```

And this is achieved with this PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "SCHEMA"."ITEM_PATHS" ("ID", "ID_PATH") AS
SELECT 
    pci."ID",
    substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(pci.id, '\'), 2)  AS ID_PATH
  FROM schema.parent_child_items pci
    START WITH parent_id IS NULL
    CONNECT BY prior id = parent_id;
```

So, even in a db, it's not a trivial problem. However, I believe the db is better equipped to deal with larger datasets.

Comment: Question says "for *each of the known child nodes* I need to find a root node", so while this should find all root nodes, it doesn't provide that mapping...

Comment: @filbranden You are right, I already have most of the root nodes; finding root nodes alone is much easier problem than labelling each node with its root node.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a good problem for a DB, especially if your data set is much larger than memory...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you use an iterative approach that will go one level deeper on each step until no further progress is possible, at which point you have found the root. So the first step would take a `parent child` pair and find the first ancestor, outputting a `grandparent child` pair, the second step would then output a `great-grandparent child` pair, and so on.

You can implement that using [`join(1)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation), where you can match the first field of one file to the second field of the other file, therefore replacing a node with its parent. `join(1)` requires that the files are sorted and that can be easily accomplished using [`sort(1)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation).

You can accomplish that using the script below. It assumes input file `nodes.txt` has one pair of whitespace separated `parent child` nodes on each line. It will produce a resulting `roots.txt` with lines that have `root child` pairs on each line.

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
sort -k 2 nodes.txt -o nodes.bychild
: >roots.txt
sort -k 1 nodes.txt -o nodes.0
depth=0
while [[ -s nodes.0 ]]; do
  echo "Depth: $((depth++)) - $(date)"
  join -1 2 -2 1 -o '1.1 2.2' nodes.bychild nodes.0 | sort -k 1 -o nodes.1
  # Nodes not present in nodes.1 have
  # their root in nodes.0 already:
  join -1 2 -2 1 -v 2 -o '2.1 2.2' nodes.bychild nodes.0 >>roots.txt
  # Next step:
  mv nodes.1 nodes.0
done
rm nodes.0 nodes.bychild
sort -k 2 roots.txt -o roots.txt
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##fVHfa8JADH6/vyK4gYpUenetDofCcHuT7WVvIqO2B3XTXmkPf8D@9y7ptVcF2UOTfMmX5OtlG5VpVcWRgUWmE1WOzdkwdc51YWC1/Fp@rFYvn2/zJSsp4/2AAMcDTzdge4nT3T5hM1gUWhs7pe3g9zp8lqjcpHOfnbBTwXoNXtnWYLN5hkQzABWnGnqvRJ3B42BQN41GwyF4CJPIqGEPad96l4HHUZwncB9u6fMxwrHo3yp0G36hk@dEcRz1YGO0BvJClSozgMMbAqTRUdUsk6pdAfS3XdmHaF@oKLnM7mg6UoTCxP/CFlcvSHveFT5baVROMw9HJ8Q9o84UKw6u//Yg3dXcVBLRraDLd@gUg7e/OperVBWKZgIkkxDgJwUZQjJgIYScjCAjySCFytw6YZ20DvkSadw67JGcIGFuIxs2MWcYce6j88kT9usMF3UobCwtkA0KGhi0OGwToctMXGrS5aZdcnqVfWJ/) for a small sample input.

This approach requires that you have roughly 5 times the size of the dataset of free space in your hard drive (one for the index `nodes.bychild`, two for `nodes.0` and `nodes.1` which for some time exist at the same time, one for sorting and one for the resulting `roots.txt` file.)

There are two calls of `join(1)` on each iteration, one of them to go one level deeper and another one (using `-v`) to find the cases where a match does not exist, which is used to detect when a root node has been found. This starts exposing some of the shortcomings of `join(1)`, having a more flexible tool would be able to get both those tasks done in a single step. Another advantage of a more flexible tool would be to keep the path from child all the way to the root, which is not that obvious to do with `join(1)` alone. Replacing `join(1)` with a simple tool written in a higher level language such as Python would probably go a long way in making this script a lot more powerful.

---

### Complexity analysis

The `join(1)` tool is a good one to use since it uses O(1) space and takes O(n) time. Since it requires the files to be sorted, it considers only one line of each file at a time, advancing the one that's behind (or both at the same time when they match), therefore constant space. Since it only reads each line of each file once, it executes in linear time.

So the important factor in the complexity of the loop is `sort(1)`, which takes O(n log n) time. The implementation of Unix `sort(1)` uses temporary files to store temporary results when the input is significantly large, so it's possible to sort a dataset much larger than memory. The temporary diskspace used by `sort(1)` uses O(n) space (already mentioned on disk requirements above.)

Since each loop iteration takes O(n log n) time, the total runtime will be proportionate to running this loop as many times as there are levels between children and their roots. The pathological worst case is when there's a single chain from a child all the way to the root, in which case depth will be *n* and the algorithm will take O(n² log n), but in most practical cases it's expected that depth will be much lower than *n* so the time complexity is much smaller than that.

Furthermore, as you start getting into the long tail of nodes with larger depth, *n* will typically be getting smaller quite faster, so in your case it's probably easier to consider a factor of 5-10 (typical depth) rather than 100 (worst case depth for the long tail.)

An obvious improvement here would be to consider the output from previous steps in calculating the current step. For instance, if I have established a (3->2->1) relationship and a (5->4->3) relationship, I should be able to go directly to (5->1) rather than (5->2). The further steps will go exponentially quicker as well (e.g. 9->5 and 5->1 going to 9->1, which would take 8 steps with the current approach but only 3 with the optimized one.) This would take the pathological case to a O(n log² n) complexity (since the depth is now exponential, it only takes O(log n) steps to get to the maximum) and would probably be quite helpful on the normal case as well.

It's probably possible to implement that using `join(1)`, but as mentioned before, a more flexible script written in a higher level language would probably be much better for such an approach (for example, merging lines from multiple sources intelligently, that is tailored for the specific algorithm.)

If this is a common use case of yours, maybe spend time implementing such a smarter approach. If it's a one-off, then the quick-and-dirty script above might be enough...

(If it's an important use case, use a database instead!)

Answer (score 1):

**IF** I understood well your description and requirements, it seems you have to rebuild a tree from a set of hierarchically related nodes.

I second all other people's comments about the fact that this is a job for a proper DB engine, but if you must do with standard command-line tools, then one other alternative might be using the filesystem as a "database", namely as an index for your nodes.

Getting to the final result would thus require 2 passes of all your nodes:

- first pass from the input data-set to create a representation of it on the filesystem, where each single node would be a directory containing a symlink to its parent node/directory
- second pass to traverse all nodes upwards to their roots and then display each node along with its parent and root as you requested

As conceptually simple as this is, it absolutely does have some notable down-sides.

The main down-side is basically that you'd be dependent on the features of the filesystem you use, and that you'd very likely need to prepare a dedicated filesystem crafted for this purpose by taking into consideration:

- filesystem's performance in dealing with millions of directories contained in one single directory: ext4 for example is not very good at this as it degrades a lot after just a few tens of thousands; xfs is better than ext4, but maybe the best choices for this aspect would be reiserfs (probably the best) or btrfs (a bit less quick than reiserfs); however, with the figures you mentioned, even with btrfs or reiserfs you'd still need to partition the amount of nodes/directories into several intermediate (sub-levels of) sub-directories so that you never let more than ~1M directories in any one single directory
- filesystem's compactness (disk space required) in storing so many nodes/directories where each would contain just one symlink and (after the second pass) one very small file: here you should afford a big waste of disk space because filesystems' standard configurations typically allocate 4k per each directory or file, making a total of 8-12k per each node, and although filesystems allow some tuning for this at formatting time, specifically the minimum allocation size, I would expect no less than 2-3k per each node; you might get more compact than that by storing nodes' parents and roots in [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) instead of symlinks and files, but still would make probably not less than 1k per each node

Another down-side might be what language you use to handle all this: using a shell script would be *very* slow for the first pass because each single node would require an `mkdir` and a `ln -s` (or a `setfattr` on Linux, `xattr` on MacOS) to link to its parent, which means 2 forks-and-execs multiplied by tens of millions of times. This fork-and-exec thing could be neutralized if you can develop the entire first pass in a language that allows you to use the involved system-calls directly, which are mkdir(2) and symlink(2)/setxattr(2).

Concretely, a simple *example* script for the first pass (mostly as a pseudo-code just to show the basic operations to apply) might be:

```bash
while read -r child parent; do
    # here I use '-p' only for 'no error if existing'
    mkdir -p $child $parent  # <-- note lack of quotes for once, so to ignore empty $parent
    [ $parent ] && (cd $child && ln -s ../${parent} parent)
done
```

The script assumes each child/parent pair is separated by space and on a line on its own, and expects the already known roots as a line each with just one ID (i.e. no parent), everything provided on stdin.

For simplicity of demonstration, the script does *not* use intermediate subdirectories, i.e. it creates all nodes/dirs in one (actually current) directory. As said, *this is a no-no* when having more than 1M nodes.

Providing one (or more) sublevel(s) of directories requires knowledge of the nodes' IDs characteristics, in order to choose the best partitioning approach. For example, if the actual address-space used by your 20-digits IDs is evenly distributed, you might go with a simple modulo operation, possibly repeated at additional levels of sub-directories. The important point is that any sub-level can be computed from the ID, which means for example that you cannot use a mere increasing counter at each node added.

Should you come out still alive (;-)) from the first pass, the second pass might even be a breeze, even with just a shell script like the one below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# make sure $PWD has physical dir
cd -P .
fs="${1:-$PWD}"

# for each node
while read -r node; do
    cd "$node"
    # check that node does not already have a root: if it does, read that and do not enter the loop
    while ! { [ -e myroot ] && read -r root < myroot; }; do
        # remember visited node
        traversed+=("$node")
        # if node does not have parent it is a root, so quit loop
        [ -L parent ] || { root="$node" && parents+=() && break; }
        # go up to parent, which becomes node to consider
        cd -P parent
        node="$PWD"
        # add to visited parents
        parents+=("$node")
    done
    # cd back to the root of this filesystem
    cd "$fs"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#traversed[@]}; i++)) ; do
        # for each traversed node (if any) set its root and display it
        echo "$root" > "${traversed[i]}/myroot"
        echo "${traversed[i]##*/}" "${parents[i]##*/}" "${root##*/}"
    done
    traversed=()
    parents=()
done < <(find "$fs" -mindepth "$((${2:-0}+1))" -type d)
```

*Note though that a compiled language could naturally be quicker, and would certainly be a lot quicker if you store parents and roots in each node/dir's extended attributes instead of in symlinks and files*

This script never needs to fork-and-exec, and marks parents encountered while traversing nodes upwards so to never traverse a branch more than once. It also allows any fixed number of intermediate subdirectories containing the actual nodes, and it expects the filesystem's root and the number of intermediate subdirectories as arguments, so you would run it like in:

```
traverse.sh /mnt/dataset-on-filesystem 3
```

where `3` would mean 3 levels of subdirectories before the nodes own directories.

The procedure used by this script would greatly benefit from receiving the deepest chains first, provided that they are also shared by many other shallower chains, because that would mark many parents at an early stage so that many following chains would need much less traversing and thus the script would consume all nodes much more quickly.

After running this, besides having the full desired output on stdout, you'd also have each node's root stored in the node's dir's `myroot` file, which you could then just `cat` at will any time.

Finally, note that many details of this solution can have room for optimizations besides the filesystem's features, e.g. by doing some caching during the two passes, or depending on whether (or how) your IDs can be packed besides being 20 digits long, or depending on their actual address-space and its sparseness, and of course depending on how already (un-)ordered the input data-set is.

Comment: Could you give an estimation of disk space used?

Comment: @wassrubleff at a purely logical level, one dir for each single child node. Then it depends on what filesystem you use. You might incur in inodes number limits because every dir is an inode. Physical space occupied for each directory again depends on the filesystem used. Then each symlink would be as big as the number of characters of the ID used plus `../`

Comment: For the purposes of my specific situation, let's assume it's MacOS, APFS, 2 TB SSD (1.76TB to be precise), High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: @wassrubleff I'm not at all expert on MacOS, even less on APFS, but it is reported to accept as many as 2^63 number of files [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System ]. So basically no limits there. Wrt to space occupied, you mentioned 20 digits each ID, plus 3 for the `../`, multiplied by the total number of single IDs would make a good estimate for disk space required

Comment: So what would be your rough estimate for disk space  required?

Comment: @wassrubleff you didn't say how many single IDs you have.. or I didn't see it in Q nor in your comments

Comment: LL3 Roughy 50M to 100M of pairs, which means exactly the same number of nodes (plus some fraction of root nodes, which won't change the order of magnitude).

Comment: @wassrubleff mmh.. then no, this idea is not an option. Besides the number alone, which might still be approachable, I thought better that Linux filesystems on their leanest configurations allocate at least 1k for each file no-matter-what. Assuming 100M records it would make 100GB+ for a complete representation of that data-set.. I don't feel like to complete this draft answer then, sorry. Actually I'll probably delete it within the next few hours, just to let you read this comment

Comment: Could you keep it, for the sake of breadth of ideas to consider for myself and potential future readers?

Comment: @wassrubleff of course, no problem. I will just edit it then to state clearly that it's an incomplete answer (I hadn't provided a full script to extract the roots of all nodes, the one in the current answer is only a sample proof-of-concept)

Comment: @wassrubleff After all I decided to write down a more complete answer. I enjoyed doing it but, given the problem, my answer is still only a best effort because I couldn't really test much. Hope it helps anyway, if just to decline the solution!